# Can you trade options with market scoring rules?

Tags: options, option-pricing, market-making, market, financial-markets

In a double-auction market, buyers and sellers are always balanced in number -- a traditional market-maker in such markets doesn't really hold any assets/take any position long-term.

However, with a logarithmic market maker, the market maker holds the opposite side of every trade, and the price actually *depends* on the imbalance in the number of "YES" and "NO" stocks issued (if they are equal, all prices will just be $0.5).

In particular in an option market, the market maker may trade with option-buyers and option-writers, and you can end up with more options written than bought.

How, then, does a market-maker know when to exercise the options it holds (i.e. make the option-writers "pay up")?

Comment: Pleas don't ask the same question in economics, personal finance and here. [Cross posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/989943) is discouraged.